# Items changed event for JavaFX ListView control

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I am looking for something like an `Item Changed Event` or `Item Count Changed Event` for JavaFX `ListView` control or lets just say in general for any collection type control.

It is because, I have some Buttons, that I want to be enabled only when there is at least one item in ListView otherwise that Button should be in disabled state.

It is my guess that perhaps adding a `ChangeListener` to the `ListView` control. would that be a right approach.

Any suggestions how can we achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

The JavaFX `Listview` provides a method with the signature

```
public final ObservableList<T> getItems()
```

You can add a listener to the observable list which will be called whenever items are added to or removed from the `ListView`.

```
aListView.getItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change change) {
        System.out.println("Detected a change! ");
    }
});
```

Similar functionality is also provided by the other 'collection' controls.

Comment: that's perfect this is exactly what I am looking for. Will give it a try now. Thanks.

Comment: Note that most of the JavaFX controls that return a 'collection' usually return one of the observable collections such as `ObservableMap` or `ObservableList`.

Comment: yes correct, that I knew but didn't know I can just add event on it.

Although, this solution wouldn't work.

I added that Listener in `public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {` method. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Care should be taken to never call `setItems(...)` or `itemsProperty().set(...)` if you only put the listener on the `ObservableList`.  Make sure to call `getItems().setAll(...)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Add a binding based on the `ListView` items using [`Bindings.isEmpty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#isEmpty-javafx.collections.ObservableList-)

```
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(listView.getItems()));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work when someone calls `ListView#setItems` and completely changes the observable list:

```
InvalidationListener updateScrollBarListener = ...

aListView.itemsProperty().addListener((obs, old, current) -> {
  if(old != null) {
    old.removeListener(updateScrollBarListener);
  }
  if(current != null) {
    current.addListener(updateScrollBarListener);
  }
});
```

I've been looking for a way to to make this a bit shorter (perhaps with `Bindings`) but haven't found it so far.